# Investigating a diff error in a bash script when variables are used instead of hardcoded file names

Tags: bash, macos, echo, diff

I have a script that looks for files of specific type in a specified directory and if they are present, generates a file with the basenames before creating a tar.gz.  Once compressed, I check to ensure the tarball contains all the files by running a diff check.

I have created a pair of variables that are the pre-compressed file list and those found in the tarball.  When I run an **if** statement including **diff** of the variables, I receive this error:

```
diff: missing operand after `/my/original/dir/filelist.txt'
diff: Try `diff --help' for more information.
```

I worked around this by referencing the files themselves rather than the created variables.  If I run the if statement in a separate bash script, it works just fine using the variables so I am entirely lost as to what my error is in my larger script.  Below I provide both the snippet from the large script and the diff statement as its own script for reference.

The if diff in its own script:

```
#!/bin/sh
filelist=(filelist.txt)
tarfiles=(tarfiles.txt)
#differences=$(diff filelist.txt tarfiles.txt) #Uncomment if below fails
differences=$(diff $filelist $tarfiles)
if $differences > /dev/null ; then  
  echo Same
else
  echo Different
fi
```

The above works just fine.

Now including this at the end my larger script:

```
TARFILES=$(tar -tzf "$ARCHIVES/tarredfiles.tar.gz" | awk -F/ '{ if($NF != "") print $NF }' > $LOGS/tarfiles.txt)

FILELIST=($LOGS/filelist.txt)

#Check to see if it all worked

DIFF=$(diff $FILELIST $TARFILES)    

cd $LOGS #I shouldn't need to do this but I do as a safety mechanism

#if diff filelist.txt tarfiles.txt > /dev/null ; then

if diff $FILELIST $TARFILES > /dev/null ; then
    echo "Today's files have been archived and checked."
else
    echo "Some or none of today's files have been archived, check the logs to find the error."
    echo (diff $TARFILES $FILELIST) > $LOGS/$(date '+%Y%m%d')errors.txt

fi
```

I have tried enclosing the variables in "" and it didn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: outside of your script, have you created small test dir for this? Have you done `cat filelist.txt tarfiles.txt` and confirmed (assuming correct sets of files) that those lists are in same sort order, that the format of the listing is the same, that there are no  leading or trailing whitespace chars on lines? Finally did you look at output (from cmd-line) of `diff filelst.txt tarfiles.txt`? While your code looks appropriate, we don't much about what exactly your error looks like AND what testing you have done on your project. Good luck.!

Comment: The error msg `missing operand after "/my/original/dir/filelist.txt"` indicates that the variable for tarfiles is not appearing on the cmd line. Use `set -vx` to see code execute with lines beginning with `+` indicating exact command being executed with all variables expanded to their values. Sorry I missed that you have clearly described your error msgs, but confirming your data is correct is still an important step. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you for the tips on using set -vx.  This will be very useful for me as I write more scripts.

Comment: The line `filelist=(filelist.txt)` creates an ARRAY with one key/value pair. To read the value of that array element, you would use `${filelist[0]}`, not just `$filelist`.

Comment: ...or `"${filelist[@]}"`, to expand to every filename in the array.

Comment: In my script I use this near the beginning: `if [ "${#NEWFILES[@]}" -gt 0 ]; then 
    basename "${NEWFILES[@]}"> $LOGS/filelist.txt` and then continue on with the if statements.  On first execution, I ran into the exact issue you described and made the change.  It is good to make note of it again.

Comment: BTW, consider using lower-case names for your variables. See the relevant standard at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html, fourth paragraph -- names with at least one lower-case character are reserved for application use, whereas all-caps names can potentially conflict with names having meaning to the shell or system. (The relevant standard is specific to environment variables, but shell variables share a namespace, as setting a shell variable with the same name as an environment variable will overwrite the latter).

Comment: Thank you for the tip.  I will adjust accordingly.  I had made them all caps for ease of me reading through and following what I was doing, but I do want to stick with conventions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you populate `TARFILES` results in it being empty. What is it that you're trying to store in the variable?

This line

```
TARFILES=$(tar -tzf "$ARCHIVES/tarredfiles.tar.gz" | awk -F/ '{ if($NF != "") print $NF }' > $LOGS/tarfiles.txt)
```

Does the following steps

- Extracts a list of the filenames (`-t`) from the compressed (`-z`) tar file (`-f`) named `tarredfiles.tar.gz` in the directory referred to by the `$ARCHIVES` variables
- Sends (pipes) that list of filenames into `awk` where you print the last component of the filename, that is the last field (`$NF`) of each line when it is split by `/` (`-F/`)
- Sends (redirects) all of that output into the log file `$LOGS/tarfiles.txt`
- Captures any other output (of which there will be none!) and stores it in the `TARFILES` variable.

So, the *variable* `TARFILES` is always empty, but the *file* `tarfiles.txt` has content in it.

It seems that you want the `diff` to compare the content of `tarfiles.txt` with the content of `filelist.txt`, but you're trying to use your variables in a way that isn't really compatible with that.

An expression of the form:

```
TARFILES=$( command goes here )
```

captures the *output* of that command.

And

```
TARFILES=$( command goes here > some-file.txt )
```

sends the output of the command into the file, and then captures ***nothing***.

What you want is something like:

```
TARFILES=some-file.txt
command goes here > $TARFILES
```

which will set the variable to be the *name* of your file, and then run a command which put content into that file.

So, specifically:

```
TARFILES=$LOGS/tarfiles.txt
tar -tzf "$ARCHIVES/tarredfiles.tar.gz" | awk -F/ '{ if($NF != "") print $NF }' > $TARFILES
```

When working will shell scripts, it is very common to be running commands that produce output that goes into files, etc. One thing you need to be really clear about in the logic of your script is when you want your variables to contain actual content (that is, the *output* of a command), and when you want them to contain filenames.

In your case you want to run diff on 2 files ("tarfiles" and "filelist") that happen to contain a list of filenames, so that means there's a little bit more to keep track of, but essentially you want to populate "tarfiles" with the output from a command, and then run a diff where you pass in the 2 files names "tarfiles" and "filelist". So you never want to use `$( ... )` to populate `tarfiles.txt` because that is how you capture the output of a command into a variable, and what you're trying to do is store a filename in your variable.

Comment: Thank you for looking. tarfiles.txt is populated using '>' and I can verify this by running the first script after it is generated in the long script. I can also uncomment" `if diff filelist.txt tarfiles.txt > /dev/null ; then` with success.  Only when I try to use $FILELIST does diff fail with `diff: missing operand after `/.../logs/filelist.txt'`  I did try your suggestion using tee | but only the first file from the tarball was returned with: `diff: extra operand `firstfile.txt'`

Comment: My question *What is it that you're trying to store in the variable?* is important, and you didn't answer it. I can't quite tell what you're trying to achieve here. I can see where things are going wrong - it's clear that the steps you're taking will not produce a working result - but I can't give you advice on how to fix it without understanding what you're trying to do. From your comment, I'm now guessing that you want `TARFILES` to refer to the file `tarfiles.txt`. If that's what you want then I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thanks again.  $TARFILES returns the contents stored in tarfiles.txt which is a list of filenames (only) in a previously generated tarball and this is compared with $FILELIST which references filelist.txt and it contains the filenames of files that should have been compressed into the tarball.  So I have a directory of files, I list them and write to a file.  I then tar the files and I am trying to check to see if all files were compressed.  I search inside the tarball, save it and then I try to run diff.  If I explicitly reference the files it works or when I run the diff in another script.

Comment: Thank you. Your explanation is very clear and I understand my error now and your solution works perfectly.  I was hung up on the tarfiles.txt having content without realizing that $TARFILES was empty.  Many thanks for the detailed response.